# 404 error in Android webview with Okta sign in

Tags: android, google-chrome, xamarin, webview, okta

I am trying to resolve a problem I am having when trying to signin using okta from a html in a xamarin webview.

If I try my html (that is using Okta Sign in widget) in Chrome, this works fine. But when I turn on device emulation from dev tools I can see the next error in the network tab:

GET https:///api/v1/sessions/me 404 (Not found)
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

I have seen that is something that is only failing in android using WebView of Xamarin Forms.

For that I am using this:

[WebView Renderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWrAe.png)

Also, I have tested the url I am loading in the webview in Edge and is working fine, also for Chrome desktop.

In other words, it is only failing when using Chrome with device emulation or Webview in Xamarin.

Seems to be something related with cookies and CORS policy but no idea how to continue.

Thank you in advance for your help.

200 Result when doing the request.